# Using PHP "include" function adds a second header to page

Tags: php, html, css, head

I've just updated my site to use the PHP "include" function to add a CSS menu to every page. When I look at the result of the include function online, it has added a second HTML and Head to each page. The web site and menu work perfectly but this looks like bad design to me.

My CSS code is in an HTML file called menu.html. I've tried to remove the HTML and Head code from the menu.html file hoping to avoid the second instance in the final result but it doesn't work. The menu doesn't display correctly.

Is this a problem or should I do something else to eliminate the second insertion of the HTML and Head?

Here is partial code from a file using the "include" function to call the menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META http-equiv="title" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="30 days">
<META NAME="classification" CONTENT="travel">
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="all">
<META NAME="distribution" CONTENT="global">
<META NAME="products" CONTENT="Travel Photos">

<TITLE>Gary and Nancy's Photo Gallery</TITLE>
<link Rel=Stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
</HEAD>


<font class=a24b color="#937666">Gary and Nancy's Photo Gallery</font>
<br><br>

<div class="menu">
<?php include 'menu.html';?>
</div>

<br>
```

Here is partial code of the menu.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbcsmbmcp.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="mbmcpebul_wrapper" style="max-width: 804px;">
  <ul id="mbmcpebul_table" class="mbmcpebul_menulist css_menu">
  <li class="first_button"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient38" style="width: 62px;"><a href="index.php" class="button_1">Home</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient38" style="width: 94px;"><div class="arrow"><a>Australia</a></div></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu gradient116">
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29 first_item"><a href="cairns.php" title="">Cairns</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29"><a href="heron.php" title="">Heron Island</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29"><a href="pdouglas.php" title="">Port Douglas</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29 last_item"><a href="mb.php" title="">Great Barrier Reef</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

Here is the resulting code that I see online i.e. including double HTML and HEAD:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META http-equiv="title" CONTENT="Gary and Nancy's travel photo gallery">
<META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="30 days">
<META NAME="classification" CONTENT="travel">
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="all">
<META NAME="distribution" CONTENT="global">
<META NAME="products" CONTENT="Travel Photos">

<TITLE>Gary and Nancy's Photo Gallery</TITLE>
<link Rel=Stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
</HEAD>

<Body>

<center>

<font class=a24b color="#937666">Gary and Nancy's Photo Gallery</font>
<br><br>

<div class="menu">
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbcsmbmcp.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


<div id="mbmcpebul_wrapper" style="max-width: 804px;">
  <ul id="mbmcpebul_table" class="mbmcpebul_menulist css_menu">
  <li class="first_button"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient38" style="width: 62px;"><a href="index.php" class="button_1">Home</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient38" style="width: 94px;"><div class="arrow"><a>Australia</a></div></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu gradient116">
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29 first_item"><a href="cairns.php" title="">Cairns</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29"><a href="heron.php" title="">Heron Island</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29"><a href="pdouglas.php" title="">Port Douglas</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem gradient29 last_item"><a href="mb.php" title="">Great Barrier Reef</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

Comment: Well, yes. `include()` includes the *entire* file, so if your `menu.html` file contains the HTML header, that's also included.

Answer (score 3):

> "this looks like bad design to me"

...yep. You should not have a HTML document inside another one. Get rid of the inner one.

Menu.html should contain the HTML specific to the menu, and nothing else. Then you can slot it into the body of your main document using include(). You probably need to keep the stylesheet link, too

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of all the header information on menu.html, just keep this line below (put it in the header of the main file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbcsmbmcp.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: That works! Thank you for the responses! In my previous effort to remove the header from the menu file, I also deleted the stylesheet  link that you identified. That's why it didn't work. I'm still learning how to apply PHP and this helps with my education. Thank you again!